# Parameterized type: Expected one more argument

Tags: haskell

[Four years ago](https://github.com/stla/multipol/blob/master/src/MultiPol.hs) I defined a multivariate polynomial type with Haskell:

```haskell
data Polynomial = Zero
                | M Monomial
                | Polynomial :+: Polynomial
                | Polynomial :*: Polynomial
                deriving (Show, Eq)

data Monomial = Monomial {
        coefficient :: Double,
        powers      :: Seq Int
    }
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

It is restricted to `Double` coefficients and I'm trying to generalize this point. My attempt:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}

data Num a => Polynomial a = Zero
                           | M Monomial a -- <- error here
                           | Polynomial a :+: Polynomial a
                           | Polynomial a :*: Polynomial a
                             deriving (Show, Eq)

data Num a => Monomial a = Monomial {
                             coefficient :: a,
                             powers      :: Seq Int
                           }
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

gives this error:

> Expecting one more argument to ‘Monomial’
> Expected a type, but ‘Monomial’ has kind ‘* -> *’

Could you help me to understand what I'm doing bad?

Comment: You want `M (Monomial a)`.

Comment: Ah ok, simply. Thanks. Would you know why **DatatypeContexts** is highlighted in red in Visual Studio?

Comment: the red highlight is because it is marked as a deprecated extension by GHC

Comment: Because it's deprecated. It was a pointless and surprising feature since the beginning of Haskell. You should remove `Num a =>` from all your types, and put that in the functions instead, when needed.